# JavaScript personal "highscores"

Tags: javascript, arrays, database

I'm not trying to get it to save server side or anything, but just a onetime save, so if you refresh the page the data will be gone. I've search around here and google, couldn't find anything to do with exactly what I was saying, but maybe I was searching for wrong stuff.

```
<div id="hs">
    <center>Past 10 scores.</center>
    <p> 1. <span id="t1">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 2. <span id="t2">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 3. <span id="t3">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 4. <span id="t4">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 5. <span id="t5">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 6. <span id="t6">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 7. <span id="t7">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 8. <span id="t8">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 9. <span id="t9">N/A</span></p>
    <p> 10. <span id="t10">N/A</span></p>
    </div>
```

was trying to make it so it goes, 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1, then pushes it down and to keep newest in #1, so 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3, etc.

I have been trying numerous things, nothing has been working(not even 100% sure if js can do it how I want, so that's why I came here. It's a speed/reaction type of game. if it makes it easier, I was thinking about maybe making it only past 5.

I had to "working" so it updated one, but when it went to update another it deleted the last one, made me rather angry.
(i'm *newer* in some coding(mostly neatness of codes especially)

Comment: use `sessionStorage`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jesse! Can you show the JavaScript code you have written so far?

Comment: Please show us your code.  We can help you 200% more effectively if we can see what code you already have and fully understand what it does now and what you want it to do.

Comment: FYI, for updating the screen, it is often easier to just keep your high scores in a local javascript aray and then rebuild the relevant display HTML from scratch than it is to rearrange your existing DOM objects.  For example one simple loop would rebuild the HTML from an array of data.  If you're also trying to save these numbers across page loads, then you will want to store the data in LocalStorage so you can load it form each page.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a HTML element and add a new one like this:

```js
function addHighScore(score) {
    var list = document.getElementById("hs").getElementsByTagName("OL")[0];
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    list.removeChild(items[items.length - 1]);
    var newItem = document.createElement("LI");
    newItem.innerHTML = score;
    list.insertBefore(newItem, items[0]);
}

addHighScore(200);
```

```css
DIV {width: 320px;}
H1 {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div id="hs">
    <h1>Past 10 scores.</h1>
    <ol>
    <li>100</li>
    <li>90</li>
    <li>80</li>
    <li>70</li>
    <li>60</li>
    <li>50</li>
    <li>40</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>10</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I should introduce your new friend `sessionStorage`

`sessionStorage` is just like `localStorage` but it retains information for as long as the browser is open.

Saving to `sessionStorage` is really easy:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value")
```

Then, to retreive data

```
sessionStorage.getItem("key") // --> "value"
```

So, a high score example:

```
function save(score) {
  // get the scores
  var scores = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("scores")) || []
  // add the scores to the list
  scores.push(score)
  // sort the scores into the new list
  scores = scores.sort().reverse()
  // Save inside sessionStorage
  sessionStorage.setItem("scores", JSON.stringify(scores))
}
```